# (Scala, Akka) Effect of setting the dispatcher throughput=1 on Akka Flow buffer

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a pipeline with Akka flow that is using a custom dispatcher.

Akka Flow code:

```
// Pulls in data via network requests
source
  // Downstream will be sent to a different actor.
  // Also, a "buffer" of 16 elements will be created between those actors.
  .async
  .via(writeToDatabase())
  .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.dispatcher("customer-dispatcher"))
  .run()
```

Dispatcher configuration:

```
custom-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 16
  }
  throughput = 1
}
```

My understanding is that `.async` will insert a buffer of 16 elements by default

> When an asynchronous boundary is introduced, the Akka Streams API inserts a buffer between every asynchronous processing stage

Source: https://blog.colinbreck.com/maximizing-throughput-for-akka-streams/

**Question: Will setting the `throughput=1` cause the buffer to always have only 1 document?**

Answer (score 2):

No.

An Akka dispatcher is responsible for (among other things) scheduling an actor in a threadpool.  The `throughput` configuration sets the maximum number of messages an actor will process from its mailbox before another actor would be able to be scheduled on the thread.  Lower values for throughput mean more context switches and thus lower performance: the benefit in exchange is that an actor which takes a long time to process messages is less able to hog the thread.

The buffer introduced at an async boundary in Akka Streams is different and basically part of the backpressure protocol.  You can set the default size of these buffers with the `akka.stream.materializer.max-input-buffer-size` configuration option, or programmatically per async boundary by adding the `Attributes.inputBuffer` attribute to the boundary.

Akka Streams could be affected by dispatcher throughput, though the effect would be pronounced in situations where there are more stream actors than dispatcher threads.  Since the internal messages for signalling demand as well as those moving stream elements from actor to actor would be affected, it's rather unpredictable what the effect would be.

Comment: Thank you! So you're saying that the buffer is not the same as the mailbox for the stream actor? Aren't elements in a flow just being passed as a message to a different actor (in the case of an async boundary)?

Comment: Actor mailboxes are (by default) unbounded.  Across an async boundary, the elements are sent as actor messages where the actor receives a message and puts it in a buffer inside the actor.

Comment: The mailbox can be thought of as an unbounded buffer which contains both stream elements and other messages, but it's not a buffer as used in the stream.